# How do I select records more than 30 minutes old in Advantage Database Architect

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I'm trying to select records that have a field (processedDt) which is a timestamp field, where the records are less than 30 minutes old. I am brand new to Advantage Database, so what I would do in SQL Server is not working.

Here is one of the many things I've tried...

```
select processedDt from table
where processeddt > cast(timestampadd(sql_tsi_minute, -30, current_timestamp()) as sql_date)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you currently get? No records, an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach, except that the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function might be a better choice:

```
SELECT
  processedDt
FROM table
WHERE
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_MINUTE, processedDt, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) > 30 
;
```

PS: Obviously this is not a valid statement, because "table" is a reserved keyword, but I suppose your real table is named differently.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, the table is named differently. ;)